# Why isn't gradle finding buildTypes() in android studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

build.gradle (Module:app) :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/105c9d1ac149a8e46f44bf28bf36da9e

build.gradle (Project:addition) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

buildTypes {
     release {
          minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Error:(18, 0) Could not find method buildTypes() for arguments [build_i2edy7g8fpgqu097z6t6v3nr$_run_closure1@6a32a849] on root project 'addition' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I have no idea as to why this isn't working. :( and also this is my first time posting here, sorry if i'm breaking some rules.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **remove** this block from the top-level `build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried that now it's just stuck on background tasks, it's just showing this: Gradle : https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/26.0.0-beta1/support-fragment-26.0.0-beta1-sources.jar

Comment: @jame_smith It would be helpful a detail error. In any case this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question

Answer (score 0):

delete

```
buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

in your build.gradle (Project:addition)

Comment: I tried that now it's just stuck on background tasks, it's just showing this: Gradle : https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-fragment/26.0.0-beta1/support-fragment-26.0.0-beta1-sources.jar

Comment: wait for download to complete